# Mocking RestTemplate.exchange() gives URI is not absolute exception

Tags: java, mockito, resttemplate

I am trying to mock this service that calls an API using rest template and returns a List.

I am unable to mock the `restTemplate.exchange()` method. It's giving me a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute" exception.

**edit- My stupid self forgot to put http:// before the base url in the test case and that is why I was getting that. Thanks for helping and apologies for wasting your time.**

Method to be tested

```
@Value("${base-url}")
private String baseUrl;

@Override
public List<Currency> getCurrencyList() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String url = baseUrl + "/currency";
    ResponseEntity<List<Currency>> result;
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<String> dataHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    log.info(url);
    result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,dataHttpEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Currency>>() {
    });
    return result.getBody();
}
```

The Testing code

```
@Test
public void getCurrencyListTest() {
   ResponseEntity<List<Currency>> result = ResponseEntity.ok(currencyList);

    when(restTemplate.exchange( ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
            ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
            ArgumentMatchers.any(),
            ArgumentMatchers.<Class<List<Currency>>>any())).thenReturn(result);
     assertEquals(currencyList,service.getCurrencyList());
}
```

Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute

at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1088)
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:145)
at org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor.createRequest(HttpAccessor.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:721)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:682)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:627)
at com.fpts.seller.service.external.impl.DocumentServiceImpl.getCurrencyList(DocumentServiceImpl.java:34)
at com.fpts.seller.service.external.DocumentServiceImplTest.getCurrencyListTest(DocumentServiceImplTest.java:105)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:78)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:84)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:161)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: show how you are mocking restTemplate in your test class. Because you are creating a new RestTemplate in your service class, you cannot mock it with mockito. Are you using Powermock? The fact that you are getting this exception proves that your mock is not being used, it is trying to call the rest service.

Comment: `log.info(url);` What's the URL being printed, if it's not so sensitive to share.

Comment: @soufrk It's  just printing the dummy url that I have created. www.testBaseUrl.com/currency

Comment: Try passing `http://www.testBaseUrl.com/currency`.

Comment: I still don't see how this makes sense. You are mocking the restTemplate in your test class. But in your service class you are creating a new RestTemplate. how will u inject this mocking behaviour u declared in your test class to the instance that got created at runtime in your service class. In your case you would be calling real REST service. If that is the case, what's the point of mocking. U might have got rifd of the error. But the idea is flawed. Think it over. Cheers

Comment: @pvpkiran - Yes, My bad. I didn't notice that I had created the object using new. I changed it to Autowired and I am seeing that the exchange method is not returning the object that I mocked for it to return. It's returning null

Comment: of course that is what I am trying to say. In the mean while you  have already accepted an answer. :) Unless you put your full test class. it is not possible to help

Comment: @pvpkiran Have a look at this. https://codeshare.io/aYl883

Comment: when u use @Mock. You need to initialize it with MockitoAnnotations.initiMocks(this)

Comment: I have added this line to the setup method but the result is still the same. Showing result as null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172680/discussion-between-napstablook-and-pvpkiran).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give a protocol name for your baseUrl and try again please, i mean by protocol is : http or https .

For example:

```
String url = "http://" + baseUrl + "/currency";
```

Answer (score 0):

As per exception URL is not valid due to ArgumentMatcher.anString(). You should provide absolute url.